# Having 4 slider values added together after button is clicked

Tags: swift, uilabel, uislider

I have 4 sliders, with 4 labels that reflect the slider values. When I click the 'submit' button on my storyboard, I want the label 'mathvalue' (the 0 next to total points) to show the added integer total of the slider inputs. Is this possible or is there another way, possibly without sliders that works more efficiently? I asked a less specific question relating to this topic and received an answer that worked, but only with one variable, if this can be improved to allow the 4 values to be added that would be great.:

```
 `var aValue: Int {
  didSet {
     mathCriAValue.text = "\(aValue)"
  }
}

@IBAction func mathCriAChanged( sender: UISlider) {
   aValue = Int(sender.value)
}`
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  InnovationSS
//
//  Created by AJ Admin on 8/16/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 AJ Admin. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
   //The slider that the students will use to input their grades into the app
    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriASlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriAValue: UILabel!

    //label is now equal to value of slider
    @IBAction func MathCriAChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let currentValue = Int(sender.value)

        MathCriAValue.text = "\(currentValue)"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriBSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriBValue: UILabel!

    @IBAction func MathCriBChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let currentValue = Int(sender.value)

        MathCriBValue.text = "\(currentValue)"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriCSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriCValue: UILabel!

    @IBAction func MathCriCChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let currentValue = Int(sender.value)

        MathCriCValue.text = "\(currentValue)"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriDSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriDValue: UILabel!

    @IBAction func MathCriDChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let currentValue = Int(sender.value)

        MathCriDValue.text = "\(currentValue)"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var mathValue: UILabel!

    var aValue: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            MathCriAValue.text = "\(aValue)"
        }
    }
    var bValue: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            MathCriBValue.text = "\(bValue)"
        }
    }
    var cValue: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            MathCriCValue.text = "\(cValue)"
        }
    }
    var dValue: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            MathCriDValue.text = "\(dValue)"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func mathValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        aValue = Int(sender.value)
    }
}
```

[Storyboard view (corresponds with code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltour.png)

Comment: Where's your button handler? Where's your attempt to get the total? What issue are you having exactly?

Comment: Button handler? I tried 2 other times but removed them because they didn't work or caused other problems within my app. Everytime I try to do anything with integer values and any of the UI labels/sliders/buttons I get errors.

Comment: Update your question with what you've tried and clearly point out the issues you are having.

Comment: Edited it, added the answer I received from last question, only worked with one value.